# ScrollArea with PyQt5 shown but is disabled

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to plot two graphs in a tab with PyQt5. My original window size is the one by default.

[image]

This is a small example. Notice I have set the vertical (and horizontal) scroll(s) to always on but they are disabled.

In this small example I am plotting two graphs in two widgets. I was expecting to have the vertical scroll automatically enabled once the graph is loaded into the widget:

[image]

and here is what I get once I manually resize the window:

[image]

Both scrolls remain disabled. Is there a way to have these scrolls enabled? I did try the setenabled(True) method but it didn't change anything. I also set the sizeAdjustPolicy in QTDesigner to AdjustToContents but no success neither.

Here is my small reproducible code:

```
class MyQtApp(scroll_attempt.Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyQtApp, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.plot_something)

    def plot_something(self):
        mylist = []
        mylist_bis = []

        for i in range(0, 100):
            x = random.randint(1, 100)
            y = random.randint(1, 100)
            mylist.append(x)
            mylist_bis.append(y)

        fig = go.Figure()
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], y=mylist, name="plot1"))
        self.widget.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))

        fig2 = go.Figure()
        fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], y=mylist_bis, name="plot2"))
        self.widget_2.setHtml(fig2.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
```

widget and widget_2 are widgets which have been promoted to QWebEngineView.

In the .py file generated from the .ui file I have this related to the scrollArea:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(2190, 872)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 2101, 1421))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.tab)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 2071, 1361))
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2048, 1338))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.widget = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 2031, 591))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.widget_2 = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.widget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 720, 2031, 591))
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
```

In Qt Designer, the two widgets (and push button) have been created within the scrollAreaWidgetContents. Should they be outside this (ie in the scrollArea?); if so how do I do that in Qt Designer please?

Edit: here is an updated .ui file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>2203</width>
    <height>1609</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <item>
     <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 1</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
        <item>
         <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
          <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
           <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
           <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="widgetResizable">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
           <property name="geometry">
            <rect>
             <x>0</x>
             <y>0</y>
             <width>2130</width>
             <height>1462</height>
            </rect>
           </property>
           <property name="autoFillBackground">
            <bool>true</bool>
           </property>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
            <property name="geometry">
             <rect>
              <x>10</x>
              <y>30</y>
              <width>1061</width>
              <height>28</height>
             </rect>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>PushButton</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
           <widget class="QWebEngineView" name="widget_2" native="true">
            <property name="geometry">
             <rect>
              <x>20</x>
              <y>700</y>
              <width>1951</width>
              <height>751</height>
             </rect>
            </property>
           </widget>
           <widget class="QWebEngineView" name="widget" native="true">
            <property name="geometry">
             <rect>
              <x>20</x>
              <y>70</y>
              <width>1941</width>
              <height>586</height>
             </rect>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </widget>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 2</string>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>2203</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QWebEngineView</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>qwebengineview.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

The scroll bars are still disabled, but this has to do with the fact that scrollAreaWidgetContents, widget and widget_2 have still the "forbidden" icon next to them: I can't set a layout for them. What is the trick here please?

[image]

Comment: You are not using layout managers. Set a top level layout for the window, and another for the scroll area contents (in both cases, right click on an empty space of the window/scroll area and select a proper layout from the "Lay out" submenu). See [using layouts in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Comment: I added two layouts: one on the window and I set the tab widget on it and a second one within the tab, where I set the buttons and 2 widgets. Still no scroll bar available.

Comment: Ensure that all container widgets (the window, the tab page content, the scroll area content, etc.) have their own layout: if you see a small red "forbidden" icon in the Object Inspector, then you didn't properly set a layout. If you did, please provide the updated ui file (not the pyuic generated one).

Comment: I added the .ui to my original post

Comment: You did not set a layout for almost any container widget that requires. As already said, if you see a small red "forbidden" icon near a widget in the Object Inspector, it means that that widget has no layout set. You must *not* use the layouts in the widget box (those are intended for *nested* layouts), but follow what already explained in my first comment and as written in the linked documentation. Do some experiments with simpler layouts so that you better understand how layouts work in Designer, then apply what you learned to your window.

Comment: I updated the .ui file as much as I could following your advice and the link. However I am unable to set a layout for the scrollAreaWidgetContents, widget and widget_2. The layout options are all greyed out for these.

Comment: I re-set a layout on the scrollWidget and that made the forbidden sign next to scrollAreaWidgetContents to disappear. But still scroll disabled